# Open Telemetry Web-only based Metrics do not show values in Prometheus examples

Tags: angular, prometheus, metrics, open-telemetry

I have been following the Open Telemetry JavaScript based examples for browser (no not wanting to use node or any back-end) for an angular prototype.

https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/js/getting-started/browser/

The traces I can get working with Zip-kin or Jaeger but the never the metrics.  No errors, all XHR's showing as OK 200 in the network tabs etc.

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/tree/main/examples/opentelemetry-web/examples/metrics.

**otel-collector-config.yaml**

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
      http:
        include_metadata: true
        cors:
          allowed_origins:
            - http://*
            - https://*

exporters:
  prometheus:
    endpoint: "0.0.0.0:9464"
  logging:
    logLevel: debug
  zipkin:
    endpoint: "http://zipkin-all-in-one:9411/api/v2/spans"

processors:
  batch:

extensions:
  health_check:
  zpages:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:55679

service:
  extensions: [zpages, health_check]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, zipkin]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, prometheus]
```

**prometheus.yaml**

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s # Default is every 1 minute.

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'collector'
    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['collector:9464']
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3"
services:

  # Collector
  otel-collector:
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.53.0
    restart: always
    command: ["--config=/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml"]
    volumes:
      - ./otel-collector-config.yaml:/etc/otel-collector-config.yaml
    ports:
      - "9464:9464"   # Prometheus scraper
      - "4317:4317"
      - "4318:4318"   # OTLP receiver
      - "13133:13133" # health_check extension
      - "55679:55679" # zpages extension
    depends_on:
      - zipkin-all-in-one

  # Zipkin
  zipkin-all-in-one:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9411:9411"

  # Prometheus
  prometheus:
    container_name: prometheus
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yaml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "otel-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "@opentelemetry/api": "^1.3.0",
    "@opentelemetry/context-zone-peer-dep": "^1.8.0",
    "@opentelemetry/core": "^1.8.0",
    "@opentelemetry/exporter-metrics-otlp-http": "^0.34.0",
    "@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-http": "^0.34.0",
    "@opentelemetry/resources": "^1.8.0",
    "@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics": "^1.8.0",
    "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base": "^1.8.0",
    "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-web": "^1.8.0",
    "@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions": "^1.8.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.2"
  }
}
```

**telemetry-metrics.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import { DiagConsoleLogger, DiagLogLevel, diag, metrics, Meter } from '@opentelemetry/api';
import { OTLPMetricExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-metrics-otlp-http';
import { MeterProvider, PeriodicExportingMetricReader } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics';

@Injectable( {
    providedIn: 'root',
} )
export class TelemetryMetricsService implements OnDestroy {
    private readonly METRICS_EXPORTER_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:4318/v1/metrics';

    meterProvider!: MeterProvider;
    private interval: string | number | NodeJS.Timeout | undefined;
    meter!: Meter;

    init() {
        this.registerMetricsSDK();
        console.info( "registerMetricsSDK" )
    }

    private registerMetricsSDK() {
        // Optional and only needed to see the internal diagnostic logging (during development)
        diag.setLogger( new DiagConsoleLogger(), DiagLogLevel.DEBUG );

        this.meterProvider = new MeterProvider();
        metrics.setGlobalMeterProvider( this.meterProvider );

        this.meterProvider.addMetricReader( new PeriodicExportingMetricReader( {
            exporter: new OTLPMetricExporter({headers: {}}),
            exportIntervalMillis: 5000,
        } ) );

    }

    unRegisterMetricsSDK() {
        this.meterProvider.shutdown().then( () => {
            metrics.disable();
            console.info( "tel: unRegisterMetricsSDK() completed" )
        } );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.unRegisterMetricsSDK();
    }
}
```

**metrics.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { TelemetryMetricsService } from './telemetry/telemetry-metrics.service';

@Component( {
    selector: 'app-metrics-test',
    template: '<button (click)="demoMeters()">Click to Demo Meters</button>'
} )
export class MetricsComponent {

    constructor( private metricsService: TelemetryMetricsService ) { }


    demoMeters() {
        this.metricsService.init();

        const counterMeter = this.metricsService.meterProvider.getMeter( 'counter-meter' );
        const counter = counterMeter.createCounter( 'democounter', { description: 'democounter' } );

        const upDownMeter = this.metricsService.meterProvider.getMeter( 'updown-meter' );
        const upDownCounter = upDownMeter.createUpDownCounter( 'updowncounter', { description: 'updowncounter' } );

        console.info( 'Feeding meters...' );

        for ( let ix = 0; ix < 10; ix++ ) {
            counter.add( 10 );
            upDownCounter.add( 1 );
        }

        console.info( '...Finished feeding meters' );
    }
}
```

**They are visible in the console:**

[image]

**Visible in the network**

[image]

When I navigate to the Prometheus UI, none of the metrics seem to appear in the list and executing any search returns nothing.   Struggling with the documentation and void of working example, any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious error is in `prometheus.yaml`:
you have used target `collector:9464`, but collector service is `otel-collector`, so target should be `otel-collector:9464`.

I guess you will see that target is not reachable also in `up{job="collector"}` metric.

Comment: Changing from  "targets: ['collector:9464']"    to   "targets: ['otel-collector:9464']"  worked, thank you @Jan Garaj